# How can I have gridview showing a different value than its data source?

Tags: c#, gridview, data-binding, user-interface, devexpress

For example, the data source is a table that has columns "IndexName" and "PeriodDays"

... | SPX | 60 | ...
... | SPX | 90 | ...
... | HSI | 180 | ...
... | HSI | 360 | ...

On the UI, I want to have a combobox column "Available Regressions" and its repository has the following items:

regression against S&P500 over the last 60 days
regression against S&P500 over the last 90 days
regression against HK Heng Seng over the last 180 days
regression against HK Heng Seng over the last 360 days

(SPX is the ticker of S&P500 and HSI is Hong Kong Heng Seng Index)

So I want to map 2 columns in the data source to 1 column on the UI, and I want to rephrase them. What's the best way to achieve this purpose? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new column and set the Property "UnboundType" to object. In the "CustomUnboundColumnData" event you can fill this. So you dont have any link to your datasource.

Here is small example:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3354